# Bottom of Android CardView is blocked by navigation buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

I am in the process of designing a UI for my app. I am using the Android CardView to contain buttons and texts along with a scrollview. When I scroll down I cannot see the bottom of the CardView and the bottom of the card is cut off slightly by the navigation keys.

**Below is an example of what I mean**

[Top of the card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ID9Qi.png)

[Bottom of the card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yFn2.png)

**Also, here is the XML code for my layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3">



<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollIndicators="none"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    android:text="New Button"
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    android:text="New Button"
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    android:text="New Button"
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Large Text"
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
                    android:textColor="#4b1313" />

            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">


                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    android:text="New Button"
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/button6"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button5" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    android:text="New Button"
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    android:text="New Button"
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button4" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">



            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give Margin in main LinearLayout

```
marginandroid:layout_marginBootom="10dp"
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to fix the issue, nothing changed when I add it to the main layout